# htaccess - ReWrite one rule to another rule (virtual folder)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a file in root directory named `propertyid.php`

I have a `RerwiteRule` that works OK:
`RewriteRule for-sale/(.*) propertyid.php?pid=$1`

User enters this URL and same URL displays in address bar
`domain.com/for-sale/(pid)`

I want a second rule that will allow users to enter this url
`domain.com/sell/(pid)`

but I want the first URL to display in the address bar
`domain.com/for-sale/(pid)`

I have tried multiple variations of the following

```
RewriteRule ^sell$ /for-sale/propertyid.php?pid=$1
RewriteRule sell/(.*) for-sale?pid=$1
```

Comment: @ thickguru - Apparently I have made a bad job in my wording of previous questions. Thanks for editing my question. I note you removed my comment about previously searching for an answer, and it seems you highlighted code elements. I will try to follow your lead in future. If you have anything else you can point out to do / not do in future questions I will welcome your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect `/sell/(.*)` to `/for-sale/(.*)`. Your redirect rule of `/for-sale/(.*)` to `propertyid.php?pid=$1` will take care of the rest.
Just check few things:

1. `/sell/(.*)` to `/for-sale/(.*)` rule should come above
   `/for-sale/(.*)` to `propertyid.php?pid=$1` redirect rule and should
   return 301 http code for moved permanently.
2. Check for multiple redirects.

Your .htaccess should look like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^sell(.*)$  http://%{HTTP_HOST}/for-sale$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^for-sale/(.*)$  propertyid.php?pid=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your very prompt and perfect response. I tried to Vote UP, but my score is less than 15 (turns out my previous questions were badly worded). Perhaps someone else could vote this answer up.